# Campagnolo QS Front Derailleur/Shifter Compatability

Tags: road-bike, derailleur, campagnolo

I have older Campagnolo Chorus 10-speed shifters. They are marked 'Carbon BB System'.

I am replacing my front derailleur and have a spare 10-speed Record QS front derailleur. QS stands for Quick Shift. I understand that the QS system changes the ratio that operates the derailleur.

Will an older non-QS lever work with a QS front derailleur?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short the answer is Yes.

From the installation & maintenance manual

> The new QS Ergopower controls provide for fast operation and a lower shifting force if used with the new QS front derailleurs.
>
> The QS Ergopower controls and the QS front derailleurs can also be used with non-QS Ergopower controls and front derailleurs.  However in this case please note that:
>
> - QS Ergopower controls with non-QS front derailleurs could require a higher force to effect shifting.
> - Non-QS Ergopower controls with QS front derailleurs will require at least two lever movements to effect shifting.

Answer (score 2):

The answer given above is substantially correct but it is also worth noting that failure of lever 2 - the upshift lever on the ErgoPower - is significantly more frequent if:
A non QS FD is used with a QS lever
A non Campagnolo crankset is in use, even if the FD and lever "match".

As the main Campagnolo factory-appointed Warranty and Service Centre for the UK, we can assure you that the above answer is correct.